# Taylor expansion in Hoeffding's Lemma proof

Tags: inequality, taylor-series, hoeffdings-inequality

[Hoeffding's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) proof uses Taylor expansion with this statement:

From Taylor's theorem, for some $ 0\leq \theta \leq 1$

$  L(h) = L(0) + h L'(0) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 L''(h\theta) \leq \frac{1}{8}h^2 $

Why does it use $0$ in the first two terms and $h\theta$ in the last? But as I know they must be same in the Taylor.

Answer (score 12):

This is the [mean-value form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of Taylor's theorem:

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}f''(c)$$
where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$

Take $x=h$ and $c=h\theta$

Comment: thanks. Is it related to Lagrange error? and can you explain a good document for mean-value form of Taylor's theorem?

Comment: Any decent Calculus textbook.

Comment: The derivation is further down on the Wikipedia page I linked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder